# Passing value from Alamofire get request to variable

Tags: swift, httprequest, alamofire

Here is my code that parse data but I want to get jsonDictionary and assign it to another variable for using outer scope.
I've checked many answers but almost all are use print for showig outcome , I need to get value instead of showing it in console. 
Can anyone help me please to solve it

```
 public func fetchData() {
  let request = Alamofire.request("www.anyurl.com")
   request.responseJSON { data in
    if let json = data.result.value as? [String: Any] {
    guard let jsonArray = json["data"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
          return
    }
    if let jsonDictionary = jsonArray[0]["title"] as? [[String:Any]] {
         print(jsonDictionary)
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a example we get this simple Json Response.

```
{
  "success": true,
  "Message": "data retrieved successfully",
  "data": {
    "name": "Dilan",
    "age": "26",
    "country": "Sri Lanka"
  }
}
```

simply you can define public variable in somewhere in your project like

> public static var user:NSDictionary = [:]

Then you can directly assign your json response as a dictionary to that variable and use it in your project.

```
AF.request(URL(string: "someurl")!,
                   method: .get,
                   headers:AppConstants.headers)
            .validate(statusCode:200..<300)
            .validate(contentType:[AppConstants.contentTypeJson])
            .responseJSON { (response) in
                switch response.result{
                case .success(let data):
                    guard let json = data as? [String:AnyObject] else {
                        return
                    }
                    let isSuccess =  (json["success"])?.boolValue ?? false
                    if isSuccess {
                        SomeClass.user = json["data"] as? NSDictionary ?? [:]

                    }else{
                        print("false")
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error")
                }
}
```

This is the another way to do that using **Codable,Decodable**

first create Codable Struct

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - User
struct User: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let message: String
    let data: DataClass

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case success
        case message = "Message"
        case data
    }
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let name, age, country: String
}
```

then you can convert your response directly to codable object

```
AF.request(URL(string: "someurl")!,
                   method: .get,
                   headers:AppConstants.headers)
            .validate(statusCode:200..<300)
            .validate(contentType:[AppConstants.contentTypeJson])
            .responseJSON { (response) in
                switch response.result{
                case .success(let data):

                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        do {
                            SomeClass.User= try decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)
                            //this time user should be public static var user:User?
                        } catch {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error")
                }
}
```

Comment: This way is applicable but there is one thing that while assigning I can retrieve data on other file  but can't add it to struct value always return nil for me.
***************
From your  eaxmple: 
  if i have 
***************
public class Item {
    var name: String
    var detail: String
    public init(name: String, detail: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.detail = detail
    }
} 
************
public var sectionsData: [Item] = [
    Item(name: user , idetail: " lorem ipsum" ]
************
*user i took it as string for compatibility

the data will return nil

Comment: i think you need to use codable struct.check the updated answer